# How to build ARCore multiplayer using Cloud Anchor and Sceneform?

Tags: java, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

Currently I am exploring ARCore and Cloud Anchors. I was able to create one application using Sceneform and Cloud Anchors. Basically we can place one object on any surface using `device-1` and `device-2` can share the same experience using Cloud Anchors.

- After we resolve a Cloud Anchor, there is no way to listen for any change in the object transform, i.e. if the user is rotating or moving the object on `device-1`, we don't have any information about it on `device-2`
- If we want to create multiplayer experience using Cloud Anchor, the only way I have found is to sync the state of the object with a server and both devices.

My questions are:

- Is it the correct way to implement multiplayer sync in ARCore?
- What properties we need to sync if this method is possible?